# Check if group exists remotely

Tags: powershell

Can anyone tell me how to check if a local group exists on a remote computer?

I know checking locally is very simple with the command below but how can I do it remotely?

Thank you everyone in advance..!

```
[ADSI]::Exists('WinNT://./Test Group')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.` (shortcut for localhost) with the name/FQDN/IP address of the remote computer:

```
[ADSI]::Exists('WinNT://computername/Test Group')
```

If you're using variables for computer or group name you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes, otherwise the variables won't be expanded:

```
[ADSI]::Exists("WinNT://$computername/$groupname")
```

Comment: I did try that but with single quotes. Replaced it with double quotes and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: It should work with single quotes as well. Double quotes are only required if you're using variables (which aren't expanded in single quotes).

Comment: Yeah I had a variable.